# How to create test suites in Android-Studio using AndroidJUnit4?

Tags: android-studio, testing, automated-tests, junit4

There are some UI tests. It is necessary to find an opportunity to somehow group them and call
for execution by groups. Perhaps there is some option how to group tests through annotations in the BDD approach
and run different test groups through annotations? Or what other way to break tests into suites what would
it was convenient to call one suite for one environment, and the second suite for regression, for example.

Answer (score 0):

It's just test classes grouped by an annotation:

```
@RunWith(Suite.class)
@Suite.SuiteClasses({
    SomeTest1.class,
    SomeTest2.class,
    ...
})
public class SomeTestSuite {

}
```